# Exportar Lista para Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma lista e gostaria de exportar para o Excel, neste código esta trazendo os registros corretamente, só não exporta o arquivo.

Preciso adicionar mais algo ou teria outro modo de fazer?

```
CorpDAO dao = new CorpDAO();
        List<CorpCRM>  listaExport = dao.ListarCorp(produto, anomes, nome, matricula, pernumber);

        var listCarregaExcel = listaExport;
        DataGrid rptExcel = new DataGrid();
        rptExcel.DataSource = listCarregaExcel;
        rptExcel.DataBind();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");           
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Relatório_lista.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        rptExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        rptExcel = null;
        listCarregaExcel = null;
        Response.End();
```

Comment: o que está dando errado? qual a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 2):

Para webforms nós usamos isso aqui:

```
            using (var tw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw))
                {
                    var grid = new GridView();
                    grid.DataSource = RetornarDados();

                    grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                    grid.DataBind();
                    grid.RenderControl(hw);

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NOMEDOARQUIVO.xls");
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
                    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                    this.EnableViewState = false;
                    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
```